# How can I join several lines after offset in Python

Tags: qgis, python, merge

I had a layer, and I did one offset of it. But the problem is that now I have a offset but the lines are separated.

How can I join them in Python? Because I read about several function as snap, snapped line, snapped geometry, merge, etc.

I wanted to know how can join theses lines, but with Python code.

[image]

In the above image you can see the lines after offset, and the next was the code.

```
import processing

layer = iface.activeLayer()

parameters = { 'DISTANCE' : 5, #offset of 5 meters
               'INPUT' : layer, 
               'JOIN_STYLE' : 1, 
               'MITER_LIMIT' : 1, 
               'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 
               'SEGMENTS' : 8 }

processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:offsetline',
               parameters)
```

Comment: You need a code attempt in your question or it will be put on hold. Why dont you test the functions you read about?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what happened - what did the layer look like before the offset? What exactly did you do?

Comment: I put the code in the question. And the before question was that: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353074/offset-line-with-python-in-qgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I digitized your lines for producing vector layer of following image:

[image]

After running following script in Python Console of QGIS:

```
import processing

layer = iface.activeLayer()

parameters = { 'BEHAVIOR' : 0, 
               'INPUT' : layer, 
               'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 
               'REFERENCE_LAYER' : layer, 
               'TOLERANCE' : 30 }

processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:snapgeometries',
                             parameters)
```

I got following result with a tolerance of 30 meters (adapt tolerance distance for your particular case):

[image]

I hope that it helps.

Comment: Yes!!! That was amazing. If I have more questions I will put the question here because you are a crack. Thank you so much.

Comment: One question, How did you digitize the lines? If you want, I can write a new question, however you want ;)

Comment: I downloaded your image and, arbitrarily, I used this command `gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:32612 -a_ullr 438819.2292659355 4457217.5520328125 439505.5584333043 4456912.752032501 AKrls.png lines.tif` for assigning a projection. Then, I digitized all the lines where I already knew that the separation between them was only a few meters (by using this extension and projection).

Comment: Thank you very much. I put another question about the length of the lines, maybe you can know how solve that. :https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353427/how-can-i-get-the-length-of-all-lines-in-python-qgis